# How to get data from multiple editText and show in textView if one or more is empty in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

In my app there are two EditText named `name` and `age`, a TextView named `showData` and a Button. Basically what I want to do is when a user enters the data in the EditText and clicks the Button the TextView will show the output like this

> My name is `name` 
>  I'm `age` years old

So for doing this I used `If Else` inside a `setOnClickListener` and wrote the code like this,

```
if (name.isEmpty() && age.isEmpty()) {
    showData.setText(null);
}


else if (age.isEmpty()) {
    showData.setText("My name is " + name);
}

else if (name.isEmpty()) {
    showData.setText("I'm " + age + " years old");
}

else{
    showData.setText("My name is " + name + 
                     "\n I'm " + age + " years old");
}
```

I'm a beginner in both Java and Android Studio so confused about things there. It would be great if you tell me how to make the app work in standard programming with fewer codes. I mean if and editText is empty the textView won't show any data related to it.

E.G: If the user inputs only the name textView will show ***My name is `name`*** only. Or if the user inputs only the age textView will show ***I'm `age` years old*** only. Or if user gives both the textView will show both

Comment: Please remove all tags and text concerning Android Studio as it has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Your bold and other formatting is terrible. Please do without.

Comment: Sting name; But EditText nameEditText or etName to make code readable.

Comment: Reverse the logic; if not etName is empty then set text for name.

Comment: Hi @blackapps. I removed some text formattings for the bold words. I hope it is readab now. Thank you so much for your answer. Could you please kindly show me an example of the code? it would a great help

Comment: I already told you which logic you should use instead. Use the NOT operator. And you did not remove the tags i talked about.

Comment: Do someting with an edittext when it is not empty. When it contains text. Then use that text. Now you check one edittext and do something with another edittext. That makes no sense.

Comment: `setText("My name is " + name);` If 'name' is indeed an EditText then that will not even compile.

Comment: I give you an idea: if(!etName.isEmpty()) textView.setText("My name is " + etName.getText());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this would be appropriate solution in Java (hopefully I did not code a typo, as I am typing directly in the SO pane):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (!age.isEmpty()) {
    sb.append("My name is " + name);
}

if (!name.isEmpty()) {
  if (sb.length() != 0) {
    sb.append("\n");
  }
  sb.append("I'm " + age + " years old");
}

showData.setText(sb.toString());
```

By the way, if you were using Kotlin this would have been sooo much nicer.

Comment: I cannot set   !sb.isEmpty()  . It shows error. How can i solve it could you kindly say? It's my first time using "StringBuilder"

Comment: @AcpSiam as I mentioned I was coding out of memory. Regretfully, `StringBuilder` does not define the `isEmpty` method. Oh well, we need to rely on the good old `length` check. I updated my answer.

Comment: btw, the  the sb lenght should be not equal "0"  to keep the "\n"
 working...   → "sb.lenght()  !=  0 "

Comment: @AcpSiam sure thing, you are right, another mistake... i corrected in the answer for future reference too